# How to loop and output values from two separate arrays into one single string

Tags: javascript

How can I loop into two arrays and create string output from both arrays `statArr` and `typeArr` with appending some `AND` & `OR` operators?

What I am hoping to get at the output is

```
stat = 'Closed' AND type = 'RD' OR
stat = 'Closed' AND type = 'WW' OR
stat = 'Closed' AND type = 'CC' OR
stat = 'Closed' AND type = 'MB' OR
stat = 'Closed' AND type = 'CN' OR
stat = 'Investigation' AND type = 'RD' OR
stat = 'Investigation' AND type = 'WW' OR
stat = 'Investigation' AND type = 'CC' OR
stat = 'Investigation' AND type = 'MB' OR
stat = 'Investigation' AND type = 'CN'
```

```js
var statArr = ["Closed", "Investigation"];
var typeArr = ["RD", "WW", "CC", "MB", "CN" ];
var sql = "";
for (let i = 0; i < statArr.length; i++) {
  sql += "stat = " + statArr[i] + " AND Type =";
 }
 console.log(sql);
```

Comment: What should be the result?

Comment: this `stat = 'Closed' AND type = 'RD' OR
stat = 'Closed' AND type = 'WW' OR
stat = 'Closed' AND type = 'CC' OR
stat = 'Closed' AND type = 'MB' OR
stat = 'Closed' AND type = 'CN' OR
stat = 'Investigation' AND type = 'RD' OR
stat = 'Investigation' AND type = 'WW' OR
stat = 'Investigation' AND type = 'CC' OR
stat = 'Investigation' AND type = 'MB' OR
stat = 'Investigation' AND type = 'CN'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest two for loops to generate each stat/type combination, then join them with ORs. I added parentheses to each clause just to make sure precedence works as it should.

```
var statArr = ["Closed", "Investigation"];
var typeArr = ["RD", "WW", "CC", "MB", "CN" ];
var clauses = [];
for(var stat of statArr) {
  for(var type of typeArr) {
    clauses.push(`(stat = '${stat}' AND type = '${type}')`);
  }
}
var sql = clauses.join(" OR ");
```

The output is

```
(stat = 'Closed' AND type = 'RD') OR (stat = 'Closed' AND type = 'WW') OR (stat = 'Closed' AND type = 'CC') OR (stat = 'Closed' AND type = 'MB') OR (stat = 'Closed' AND type = 'CN') OR (stat = 'Investigation' AND type = 'RD') OR (stat = 'Investigation' AND type = 'WW') OR (stat = 'Investigation' AND type = 'CC') OR (stat = 'Investigation' AND type = 'MB') OR (stat = 'Investigation' AND type = 'CN')
```

However, I think you might really just want

```
stat IN ('Closed', 'Investigation') AND type IN ('RD', 'WW', 'CC', 'MB', 'CN')
```

which could be generated with

```
const quote = s => `'${s}'`;
var sql = `stat IN (${statArr.map(quote).join(", ")}) AND type IN (${typeArr.map(quote).join(", ")})`;
```

Comment: Thanks AKX, can you please also let me know how to achieve the second solution?

Answer (score 0):

Using nested for loop, you can get result.

```
    var statArr = ["Closed", "Investigation"];
    var typeArr = ["RD", "WW", "CC", "MB", "CN" ];
    var sql = "";

    for (let i=0; i<statArr.length; i++) {
        for(let j=0; j<typeArr.length; j++){
            console.log(`stat = '${statArr[i]}' AND type = '${typeArr[j]}' OR`)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will include a final `OR`, which is not desired.